# WSO2 API Manager 1.10 redirect to carbon or publisher

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have 2 stores nodes, 2 publisher nodes, 2 gateway workers, 1 Gateway Manager. The workers nodes and Gateway Manager uses a SVN Deployment Synchronizer. All machine has a apache doing a reverse proxy. I added a CA certificate using [1], except creating a own key store.

When I publish a api at Publisher node and try get it at worker node, all calling is redirecting to carbon. So, when I try [2] I receve [3].

## WORKER1

CATALINA-server.xml:

```
 <Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               port="9443"
               proxyPort="443"
               bindOnInit="false"
               sslProtocol="TLS"
               sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
               maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
               acceptorThreadCount="2"
               maxThreads="250"
               minSpareThreads="50"
               disableUploadTimeout="false"
               enableLookups="false"
               connectionUploadTimeout="120000"
               maxKeepAliveRequests="200"
               acceptCount="200"
               server="WSO2 Carbon Server"
               clientAuth="false"
               compression="on"
               scheme="https"
               secure="true"
               SSLEnabled="true"
               compressionMinSize="2048"
               noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
               compressableMimeType="text/html,text/javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript,application/xml,text/css,application/xslt+xml,text/xsl,image/gif,image/jpg,image/jpeg"
               keystoreFile="${carbon.home}/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks"
               keystorePass="wso2carbon"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

Carbon.xml

```
...
<HostName>apigateway.serpro.gov.br</HostName>
<MgtHostName>apigateway.serpro.gov.br</MgtHostName>
...
<ServerURL>local:/${carbon.context}/services/</ServerURL>
...
 <DeploymentSynchronizer>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <AutoCommit>false</AutoCommit>
    <AutoCheckout>true</AutoCheckout>
    <RepositoryType>svn</RepositoryType>
    <SvnUrl>http://<manager ip>/repos/wso2</SvnUrl>
    <SvnUser><user></SvnUser>
    <SvnPassword><password></SvnPassword>
    <SvnUrlAppendTenantId>true</SvnUrlAppendTenantId>
</DeploymentSynchronizer>
...
```

api-manager.xml

```
...
<KeyValidatorClientType>WSClient</KeyValidatorClientType>
...
<RevokeAPIURL>https://${carbon.local.ip}:${https.nio.port}/revoke</RevokeAPIURL>
...
```

[1] - http://wso2.com/library/knowledge-base/2011/08/adding-ca-certificate-authority-signed-certificate-wso2-products/

[2] - https://apigateway.serpro.gov.br/calc/1.0/divide?x=2&y=1

[3] - https://apigateway.serpro.gov.br/carbon/admin/login.jsp

Comment: Check the reverse proxy configuration. Can you post  the reverse proxy configuration to the question?

Comment: post your reverse config, maybe a problem with the ports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the apache configuration. I find it at [1] 
All APIManager configuration was works very well.

At Apache ,all calling for "/" will be redirect to :9443/

Now works well.

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Configuring+Apache+Httpd